# Windows Command Line

Tags: command-line, loops, for-loop, break

Does anyone know how to break out of a for loop when it's typed directly into the windows command-line?  I know you can use gotos and labels to break out of it when it's in a batch file, but I can't find anything about breaking out of one on the command line.  Here's a simple example:

```
C:> for /l %i in (1,0,1) do @ping -n 1 google.com || (echo ^G & msg user "Google is down!" & QUIT)
```

This should infinitely ping google.com.  If it ever fails, it beeps (echo ^G), displays a message box to the user "user" that says "Google is down!", and QUITs.  I don't know how to do the quit part though.  I guess I could do something like taskkill /f /im cmd.exe, but I was looking for something more elegant.  Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it into another instance of `cmd` and use `exit`:

```
cmd /c "for /l %i in (1,0,1) do @ping -n 1 google.com || (echo ^G & msg user "Google is down!" & exit)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Exit` instead of Quit

Comment: Only half the answer. This will kill your session instantly which is often not what you want when working on the command-line :-)